# Symfony 2 : Best practices

Tags: symfony

I would like to have a return on your experience concerning Symfony 2 projects :

1. Has anyone experience putting all of the projects inside the same enveloppe (each project is a bundle for example). why is it bad ?
2. Another solution : put the vendor folder somewhere on the server and point to it in all Symfony 2 projects (that means there is no vendor folder in the projects). What do you think about that ?

Thank you

Comment: You propose solutions but what is the problem you trying to solve?

Comment: not to repeat the use of the same vendors in the projects... just have one vendor folder..

Comment: And that creates another problem, when you update a vendor to version that breaks backwards compatibility but has feature you need, you have to update all projects not just one. Disk space is not a problem today.

Comment: for the vendors....if you deploy with capifony you only have one shared vendor, and if the vendors change capifony make the releases folders to manage this, capifony web [here](http://capifony.org/)

Comment: @mlwacosmos: Please don't go there. I had a brush with madness of trying to contain vendors to single instance (by putting each instance of application as different bundle). It really didn't go well and I had more problems than benefits from that... :(

Gustek is absolutely right. Sooner or later you will find yourself breaking BC and getting yourself a lot of headache...

Comment: You can read about Symfony's best practices here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html

Comment: It's sort of a question of a what a "project" is. You'll save some disk space by sharing vendors, but create some other issues. If you're wanting to host a lot of almost-identical projects, then it might make sense. Especially, if you are able to automate deployment of updates to each project. You could probably define "global" dependencies in `~/.composer/composer.json` and then run `composer global install`. If you added `require '~/.composer/vendor/autoload.php' to your app.php, you'd be basically there. However, what you are talking about would mean you'd no longer have a composer project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1**

It is bad because you will have a single config for each project, so a single database user etc. Not to mention best practises. There is nothing stopping you doing this, but it has bad news written all over it.

**Answer 2**

If you put the vendor folder somewhere else on the server you will not be able to have different versions of external libraries per project, which is actually important.

---

If you have common services that more than one project use then I would consider setting up APIs for each services so other projects can access it. OR you could import that bundle.